# Disable life cycle events for a web component from outside of the element scope

Tags: javascript, web-component

I am faced with a situation where I want to read a template, extract the component tag name to cache it and later to reuse it. The trouble is that when the DOM is parsed all the life cycle events are executed. Which is the normal behavior for good reasons.

**example.html** - I need to read the contents of the div before the custom compoent life cycle events are executed. Even better, to disable them completely when the `p-for` tag is defined.

```
<div p-for="menus, parent.menus">
    <vs-editor-menu-dropdown></vs-editor-menu-dropdown>
</div>
```

I noticed that If I use a `DOMParser` with the XML option it seems that the life cycle events are not executed. Even more interesting is that if I right-click an element and select "Edit as HTML", then after save the change I can see in the console output the log that tells me the "connectedCallback" was executed. So I know that Chrome at least can ignore the life cycle events.

Now the question is how can I trigger this programmatically from other regions of the code except using if clauses in the web component context. Of course, the trick would be to target it only for certain arbitrary components. I suppose MutationObserver is not an option because of the async nature of the callbaks. By the time the component was detected it is already to late to inhibit the life cycle cals.

```
let parser = new DOMParser()
parser.parseFromString(dataBind.template, "text/xml") // instead of "text/hmtl"
```

Comment: Couldn't you just delay registering the custom element and extract the `p-for` values in your main code, and register/not-register based on that?

Comment: Or have the `connectedCallback` be smart : `connectedCallback() {
        if (this.parentElement.getAttribute('p-for').includes('parent.menus')) {
          // don't run additional code.
        }
      }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've considered both of these options, but they are not good enough for the purposes I desire. The `p-for` attribute is part of a data binding library: So far I managed to get it working without requiring the web components to implement any specific change. Registering the component later is also not going to work. There could be all sorts of situation where you need to have that component registered while in some other parts of the code you would want it unregistered.

Comment: as you seemed to have solved this can you pls post your answer can see it as well :) thx